# Best solution for WebServer in Web developer's company

Tags: webserver, access-control

I'm looking for best solution about hosting web projects on linux server.
My focus is on permissions and ACL's.
Example We have **3 project** and **3 developers** , They have access to files via `Samba Share` and `SFTP`. 
I want developers and projects have community and permission like this:

```
Developer 1 --RW--> Project1
Developer 2 --R--> Project1
Developer 3 --0--> Project1

Developer 1 --R--> Project2
Developer 2 --RW--> Project2
Developer 3 --RW--> Project2
```

Set `facl` is best choice or we have another solutions better than `facl` on linux?

Answer (score 0):

> They have access to files via Samba Share and SFTP.
>
> Set facl is best choice or we have another solutions better than facl on linux?

I think switching to a more modern set of tools will serve you better in the long run. There was a time in the rickety past when version control tools were so primitive that using samba shares instead made practical sense. This is no longer the case. Drop the samba shares and break out the `git`.